# Send Http request to API with object as parameter in Angular

Tags: angular, api, http, post, get

I have a search form where I can fill in input fields in my web application. These input fields will end up in my SearchCriteria object.

Once I click on the search button, I want to send that SearchCriteria object to an API, which will return a collection of matching Order objects. Now that backend code is all in place, I just need to do the correct API call.

This is what I tried, but I always seem to get an http 400 error.

```
  getOrders(searchCriteria: SearchCriteria): Observable<Order[]> {

    let requestoptions = {
      'headers': new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
      'withCredentials': true
    };

    return this.http.post(environment.backend + "/api/orders/getOrders", searchCriteria, requestoptions).pipe(map((response: any) => {
      return response;
    }));
  }
```

The request URL will look like this:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/angular-rest/api/orders/getOrders?searchCriteria=%7B%22user%22:%7B%22firstName%22:null,%22lastName%22:null%7D,%22orderMinAmount%22:null,%22orderMaxAmount%22:null,%22orderDate%22:null,%22product%22:%22Phone%22%7D
```

/api/orders/getOrders looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "getOrders", method = POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public Collection<Order> getOrders(@RequestBody SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
    return orderService.getOrders(searchCriteria);
}
```

Now I've been reading things, but have not been able to figure it out.

What I actually want (I think) is to send the object (searchCriteria) in the request body of my http request, so the URL doesn't look that long and of course the http request is succesful.

What am I doing wrong? What could be better?

Comment: Is stringify required for sending object by your API?

Comment: @Mridul: No, it was just a try-out of mine. I edited my post and added the specific API method if that might make more sense.

Comment: You can't send a message body in a GET request. If your API accepts a POST, then use `http.post`. Otherwise map your object to params using javascript

Comment: @KurtHamilton I actually changed the API method to GET myself. The backend was already in place and originally it was on POST. I now edited my question and changed it to its original state again. What are the options now?

Comment: Second param in POST should be message body instead of options

Comment: If you can use post, remove `params` from `requestoptions` and try `post(url, JSON.stringify(object), requestoptions)`.

Comment: Thanks already to everyone, I feel like I am getting closer, I once again updated my getOrders() method to what I have now in my original post.
It seems that I am now sending the searchCriteria correctly in the body, yet still I receive a 400 status code error.
Might this still have to do anything with the api call?

Comment: Ok, the API call is fine now, I did some tweaks in my code and now it all works flawlessy. I will upvote as many as I can.
Thanks for the help all!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
   getOrders(searchCriteria: SearchCriteria): Observable<Order[]> {
          let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
          return this.http.post(environment.backend + "/api/orders/getOrders",searchCriteria, {headers})
          .pipe(map((response: any) => {
            return response;
           }));
      }
```